In C++, how can we write a recursive function that returns a range?
In C++ we face 2 problems when writing a recursive function that returns a range

the base case type is different from the recursive case type
ranges often involve lambdas, so the return type is auto, which prevents recursion

Let me illustrate with sum decompositions. Here is a strict (non lazy) solution
std::list<std::list<unsigned int>> SumDecompStrict(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return { {} }; // the sum of the empty list is 0 by convention
    std::list<std::list<unsigned int>> ret;
    for (unsigned int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        std::list<std::list<unsigned int>> ll = SumDecompStrict(n - k);
        for (auto& l : ll)
            l.push_front(k);
        ret.splice(ret.end(), std::move(ll));
    }
    return ret;
}

Now I want to convert this into a lazy generator of sum decompositions, by returning a range, which could look like this
auto SumDecompLazy(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return std::ranges::single_view<std::list<unsigned int>>({}); // the sum of the empty list is 0 by convention
    return std::views::iota(1, n+1)
        | std::views::transform([n](unsigned int k) {
            return SumDecompLazy(n - k)
                | std::views::transform([k](std::list<unsigned int>& l) { l.push_front(k); return l; });
            }
        | std::views::join;
}

But SumDecompLazy fails to compile, because of the 2 mentioned problems:

the type of std::ranges::single_view<std::list<unsigned int>>({}) is different from the type of the recursive case
auto return type prevents calling SumDecompLazy from itself

This problem is solved in other programming languages, for example by the IEnumerable type in C#, or its alias seq in F#. Is there a solution in C++?

range-V3 has any_view. std doesn't have yet...

Aside: std::list is a pretty slow container, are you only using it because of push_front and splice? I'd use std::vector, and add k at the back.

@Caleth You're quite right about std::vector. I didn't optimize this part because I was focused on the recursion problem, which you solved with std::generator. I also like Jarod42's any_view. Either way I have to wait, my company uses C++20.

C++23 has std::generator, which allows you to express this as a coroutine, either explicitly looping
std::generator<std::list<unsigned int>> SumDecompLoop(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        co_yield {};

    for (unsigned int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        for (auto l : SumDecompLoop(n - k))
        {
            l.push_front(k);
            co_yield std::move(l);
        }
    }
}

or using range adaptors
std::generator<std::list<unsigned int>> 
SumDecompRange(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        co_yield {}; 
    co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(std::views::iota(1u, n+1)
        | std::views::transform([n](unsigned int k) {
            return SumDecompRange(n - k)
                | std::views::transform([k](std::list<unsigned int> l) { l.push_front(k); return l; });
            })
        | std::views::join);
}

